# Change grey sub-header name of adapter

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

Inside Control Panel -> Network Connections I've got the following adapter for my mobile hotspot (Windows 10):

[image: Network adapter]

I can right-click to rename "Local Area Connection* 12" to something else.
I can't figure out how to change the grey "som" to something else.

Is there a way to change it?

Comment: That might be a detail exposed by the driver, so not modifiable. But it really looks strange, so might be an error. Try to delete the device in Device Manager and reboot, for the driver to be reinstalled.

Comment: I agree with harrymc -- looks strange. In my case, that middle line corresponds to the "Status" field of the Details view. Try changing the view to Details and see what shows in the Status column for that item.